# #Why in Python cleaning string manually works but creating exactly the same function does not?

Tags: python, string, function

I created some messed up strings and tried to repaired it. Eventually I have faced the problem where my function does not work but the same code typed manually works.

**Question:**
Why in Python the same code does not work in function but it does work when you code the very same code manually?

Here is the code:

```
    #A variable
    x = "apples and oranges!"

    #Making a variable messed up strings
    x = "-".join(x)
    x = str(x.split("-"))


    #Creating automatic function for cleaning messed up strings
    def clnStr(x):
        y = x
        y = y.replace("'", "")
        y = y.replace(",", "")
        y = y.replace("[", "")
        y = y.replace("]", "")
        y = y.replace(",", "")
        y = y.replace(" ", "")
    clnStr(x)
    print(x)



    #Cleaning up string variable manually
    y = x
    y = y.replace("'", "")
    y = y.replace(",", "")
    y = y.replace("[", "")
    y = y.replace("]", "")
    y = y.replace(",", "")
    y = y.replace(" ", "")
    print(y)

# Repairing string variable
for i, index in enumerate(y): #Getting a list of indexes of a string variable
    print(i, index)

y = y[0:6] + " " + y[6:9] + " " + y[9:]
print(y)


#cannot repair 'x' variable with same method because the function does not work as it should.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your `clnStr` function. Try:

```py
def clnStr(x):
    y = x
    y = y.replace("'", "")
    y = y.replace(",", "")
    y = y.replace("[", "")
    y = y.replace("]", "")
    y = y.replace(",", "")
    y = y.replace(" ", "")
    return y

z = clnStr(x)
print(z)
```